# Equality of two analytic functions based on a condition

Tags: complex-analysis

> Suppose that $f$ and $g$ are two analytic functions on the set $\phi$ of all complex numbers with $f(\frac{1}{n})=g(\frac{1}{n})$ for $n=1,2,3,\ldots$ Then show that $f(z)=g(z)$ for each $z$ in $\phi$.

I am not able to even start proving it. Can some one please help me?

Comment: It’s true in general that if two functions analytic on a region agree on a set with a limit point in the region, then they agree on the whole region

Comment: This is where the word "holomorphic" comes from.

Comment: Well, I know the first step for sure -- take $h = f - g $ and try to prove that $h = 0$ in $\phi$.

Comment: @saulspatz Interesting. Do you have a reference for that?

Comment: @zhw. No, but I remember by instructor saying way back when, "Analytic functions are like laser pictures."  Just as any small portion of a hologram suffices to recreate it, any small portion of an analytic function determines it.  When you consider that the term means "whole shape" in Greek or Latin or whatever, I think it's a fair inference.

Answer (score 0):

> **Hint:** Check the *[identity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem)*  for analytic functions:
>
> If two functions are
> analytic in a region $G$, and if they coincide in a neighborhood, however small, of a point $z_0$ of $G$, or only along a path segment, however small, of a point $z_0$ of $G$, or also only for an infinite number of distinct points with the limit point $z_0$, then the two functions are equal everywhere in $G$.